# Get all Taxonomy Terms

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have added a vocabulary as Sites with machine name as sites. I have added two custom fields in this vocabulary as :

1) URL
2) Status 0 or 1

I need to make a dropdown of all terms with status 1 something like.

> get term.name from term join vocabulary on vid where vocabulary.machine_name = sites and term.status = 1

```
$v =  taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load('sites');

$t = taxonomy_get_tree($v->vid);
```

How do I get an array of enabled terms in the 'sites' vocabulary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [`entity_load`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/entity_load/7) can be used, but you have to retrieve entity ids yourself:

```
$terms = array();

$v = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load('sites');
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$result = $query
  ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'taxonomy_term')
  ->propertyCondition('vid', $v->vid)
  ->fieldCondition('field_status', 'value', 1) // If your field name is 'field_status'
  ->execute();

if (!empty($result['taxonomy_term'])) {
  $terms = entity_load('taxonomy_term', array_keys($result['taxonomy_term']));
}

// dpm($terms);
```